# Mongodb arrayFilters

Tags: mongodb

Я использую mongodb в своем приложении nodejs. Я хочу обновить в моем файле JSON множество нотификации которые содержат `read: false`.

Пример: у меня есть 3 уведомления `notifications`, где я `read: false`, если я выполняю свой запрос на обновление, я хочу обновить эти 3 уведомления `notifications`, который содержит `read: false` и заменить на `read: true`.

Но это не работает. У меня есть это сообщение:

> (node:12884) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongoError: Unrecognized field in update operation: arrayFilters

**Model.js**

```
const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema(
{
   username: { type: String, required: true, validate: usernameValidator },
   notifications: [{
      sender_id: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User'},
      message: { type: String},
      viewProfile: { type: Boolean, default: false},
      created: { type: Date, default: Date.now()},
      read: { type: Boolean, default: false},
      date: { type: String, default: ''}
   }]
});
```

**notifiRoutes.js**

```
User.update(
    { _id: req.user._id },
    { $set: { "notifications.$[elem].read": true } },
    { arrayFilters: [ { "elem.read": false } ], multi: false }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

У меня тоже была такая проблема. Я решил ее так.

```
database.collection('userViewer').update(
                details,
                { $set:
                    {
                        "chatList.$[elem].unread" : 0
                    }
                },
                {
                  multi: false,
                  arrayFilters: [ { "elem.contactId": {$eq : data.contact} } ]
                }
            );
```

код из моего рабочего проекта... но у тебя вместо `multi: false` будет `multi: true`, потому что ты меняешь в трех местах. Если не помогло пиши.